# Retrieving list of items using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, singleton

I am trying to retrieve a list of items from a mySQL db and insert them as a list in a select object on a webpage. The following is the bit of code that isnt working.

In the first line, I am trying to retrieve a JSON object from a public function called getBrands() in a singleton object I have created called DatabaseInterface.

The second line is then attempting to turn that JSON object into a php array.

Finally, I am running a loop which can option each item in between  tags for the webpage.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php 

var $brandArrayJSON = DatabaseInterface::getBrands();
$brandArray = JSON_decode($brandArrayJSON);

for ($loop=0; $loop < sizeof($brandArray); $loop++) {
    echo "<option>$brandArray[$loop]</option>";
}

?>
```

EDIT: In case it helps, here is my DatabaseInterface singleton. I have included this file at the top of my php file

```
class databaseInterface {

private static $_instance;

// Private constructor prevents instantiation
private function __construct() {
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if (!self::$_instance) {
        self::$_instance = mysqli_connect(self::databaseHost, self::databaseUsername, self::databasePassword, self::databaseName);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno(self::$_instance)) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function getBrands() {

    try {
        $con = DatabaseInterface::getInstance();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle exception
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $query = "SELECT psBrandName from brands";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query. ".mysqli_error($con));

    $resultArray[] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        extract($row);
        $resultArray[] = $psBrandName;

    }

    return json_Encode($resultArray);

}
```

Comment: What does your generated JSON look like?

Comment: What is the concrete problem, how does it "not working"?

Comment: The problem is simply that when the script is run it crashes resulting in the webpage not loading. The JSON object is simply a list of values (brands) with no keys.

Comment: Its difficult to tell. Does that imply that the syntax above looks ok?

Comment: I have added the singleton class in case that helps...

Comment: Do you have error reporting on (E^ALL)? Reg syntax: If you aren't using an ancient PHP version (php4) you don't need to declare variables with "var". I would stick with the default function names  (JSON_decode vs json_decode). $brandArray isn't an array, it's an object. If you want an array you should do json_decode($json, true). And lastly I'd change sizeOf to count, it just seems to make more sense (to me anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing "wrong" with the code, in that it should work (provided nothing is broken on the query-side). However, there are several things that should be improved.

First, basically what the `getBrands()` method is doing is equivalent to this:

```
$brandArray = json_encode(array('test','test2','test3'));
echo $brandArray; // returns ["test","test2","test3"]
```

Now, when you decode that you get the same thing you originally put in (an array):

```
$brandArray = json_decode('["test","test2","test3"]');
var_dump($brandArray); // Will dump an array
```

Since this is an array (*not* a PHP object), you can just use a foreach.

```
foreach($brandArray as $option) {
    echo '<option>', $option, '</option>';
}
```

If you're worried about it being an object in some instances (maybe you had a non-array JS object which would be mostly the equivalent to a PHP associative array), you could cast the json_decode result into an array.

```
$brandArray = (array)$brandArray;
```

Now, in your `getBrands()` method, I would highly recommend just using `$row['psBrandName']` instead of cluttering things up with `extract`, unless you have a really good reason to do this.